# How To Remove Autofocus In BootBox

Tags: javascript, bootbox

While using Bootstrap `2.3`, [Bootbox](http://bootboxjs.com/) and viewing the result in Google Chrome on Ubuntu you get a less than appealing border around the button because it is auto-focused. I havent found any api hooks to trigger a blur event once the modal is shown. Is there a way to remove the autofocus with javascript alone or maybe just css but without the option to fork the project, remove the [autofocus](https://github.com/makeusabrew/bootbox/blob/v3.3.0/bootbox.js#L428) and make it configurable?

[image: bootbox-autofocus]

Comment: You can inspect and see if there is any class / id applied to button which will help you to select it to trigger blur() event..

Comment: Thanks Rahul -- I used `a.btn:focus { outline: none; }`

Answer (score 0):

There is no API hook, but you can do it by attaching a javascript event handler to the alert:

```
var bbAlert = bootbox.alert('Alert!')

bbAlert.on('shown.bs.modal', function(){
    $('.btn-primary').blur();
});
```